# How to send ajax success to an external php page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that will generate a data grid.

prof.php

```
function ajaxFunction(gotid){
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "profile/ajax/order.php",
  data: {id:gotid},
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
  for( i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++ ) {
  var usId = result[i]['user_id'];
  var orId = result[i]['order_id'];
  var poId = result[i]['product_id'];
  var itStat = result[i]['freelancer_st'];
  var unitp = result[i]['unit_price'];
   .... the rest of the code
```

the function works fine as I generate the grid in a popup inside the prof.php, but i have changed my mind and I want to send the success in an external php page so the grid will be generated there in list.php

Is that possible? could you give me a lead ?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just call another ajax function within your success callback.

```
function ajaxFunction(gotid){
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "profile/ajax/order.php",
  data: {id:gotid},
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'list.php',
     data: { data: JSON.serialize( result ) }
     ... etc
```

Comment: it does not passes anything to the nested ajax, i have placed an alert right after the success: function(result) { but it alerts nothing and won't generate the table in list.php either